# JavaScript to submit form automatically after field value changes without user clicking?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a web form with some fields and a submit button. I have a function that checks a file every second and outputs the value. One field imports this value and displays it.

What I need is as soon as the value on this field is changed, the submit button should be automatically clicked.

For some code:

My form name is `form1`, Here is the input field:

```
<input name="code" id="code" type="text" size="64" maxlength="128" onchange="send_data();" />
```

Here is the JavaScript function I have:

```
      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
        function send_data()
        {document.form1.submit();}
        </SCRIPT>
```

If I myself type in anything in the field and click outside it, The form will be submitted automatically. But if the value is changed automatically, nothing will happen...

Is there a possibility in Javascript to  do this?

Comment: What You mean by *value is changed automatically* ? `onchange` is en event. Event is an action that can be detected by JavaScript. I suppose that Your `automatically change` is not recognized by JS engine.

Comment: You will need to trigger a submit event where-ever you are adding a value automatically. When is this?

Comment: I have document.form1.code.value=res.cd; that gets the value from an array and displays it in the field with the "code" id.

Comment: So, after changing value of form field `document.form1.code.value=res.cd;` You need to call manually: `send_data()`. I think that `onchange` event (or another) have no chance to occur in that situation.

Comment: So the Js is not detecting the change that is occuring on the field. Is there any turnaround ?

Comment: You can trigger `onchange` event manually using something like that: `document.form1.code.onchange();`, but it is similar to call `send_data()`. I do not know a mechanism in JS to fire an event automatically when you assign values ​​to fields in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you could just compare the old value with the new one.

```
if (document.form1.code.value != res.cd)
{
    document.form1.code.value = res.cd;
    send_data();
}
```